# Schema operation failed: Unknown property 'read_repair' , 'additional_write_policy'

Tags: cassandra

I am using the following cassandra servers and while trying to create a table name I am getting following error.

```
2023-09-11 13:57:55,961 [info] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Connected to Cassandra cluster: Amazon Keyspaces
2023-09-11 13:57:55,961 [info] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Creating schema using file '/tmp/schema.cql', keyspace: '<keyspace>'
2023-09-11 13:57:55,981 [warn] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Schema operation failed: Unknown property 'read_repair'
2023-09-11 13:57:55,983 [warn] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Schema operation failed: Unknown property 'additional_write_policy'
2023-09-11 13:57:55,983 [info] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Finished creating schema
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table wilshire_dev_lineage_stats.stats
  at com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CQLExecutor.<init>(CQLExecutor.java:30)
  while locating com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CQLExecutor
    for the 2nd parameter of com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CassandraRepository.<init>(CassandraRepository.java:47)
  at com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CassandraRepository.class(CassandraRepository.java:41)
  while locating com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CassandraRepository
  while locating com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.StatisticsRepository
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table wilshire_dev_lineage_stats.stats
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:49)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:86)
        at com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CQLExecutor.<init>(CQLExecutor.java:37)
        at com.ac.lineage.stats.repository.cassandra.CQLExecutor$$FastClassByGuice$$7a988c18.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:213)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
        at play.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceBuilder.java:211)
        at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.java:121)
        at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.java:32)
        at play.api.ApplicationLoader$JavaApplicationLoaderAdapter$1.load(ApplicationLoader.scala:181)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:53)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:29)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table wilshire_dev_lineage_stats.stats
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:181)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:250)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:219)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:213)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:202)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Cassandra Versions :

```
[cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.stats_summary (
    dataset_id text,
    snapshot_end timestamp,
    snapshot_start timestamp,
    dataview_name text,
    datamodel_id text,
    summary text,
    PRIMARY KEY (dataset_id, snapshot_end, snapshot_start, dataview_name, datamodel_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (snapshot_end DESC, snapshot_start DESC, dataview_name ASC, datamodel_id ASC)
AND additional_write_policy = '99p'
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND cdc = false
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND default_time_to_live = 0
```

My questions :

1. Under which version read_repair & additional_write_policy properties where added to Cassandra ?
2. How can I find which version started these properties on my own ?

Regards,
BKV

If I rewrite the create statement with all additional properties removed I can create the table.

Comment: Is the `CREATE TABLE` statement being passed from within an application?  I'd create that in the cluster first, and not from within code.  Otherwise schema mismatches are a distinct possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when those properties were introduced, but it looks like `additional_write_policy` was going to be renamed as a part of [CASSANDRA-14761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14761).  However, that never made it in, as that ticket is not yet resolved.

That being said, it looks like that property is new as of Cassandra 4.0.  I also just tried your table CQL from above, and it worked in 4.0, 4.1, and the new Cassandra 5.0 alpha version.

```
Connected to Cassandra cluster: Amazon Keyspaces
```

However, if you are using Amazon Keyspaces, then it's anybody's guess as to which table properties are valid.  The list of compatibility issues between Apache Cassandra and Amazon Keyspaces is well known.  I wouldn't be surprised if this was an issue with Keyspaces, but not with Cassandra.

If you wanted to find out when certain table properties were added to the project, you could probably search through the Cassandra JIRA project.  To get there, simply follow the link for [CASSANDRA-14761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14761).

Comment: thank you for pointing to the Cassandra Jira project, was able to go through the list and find more information. 

Regards,
BKV

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to recreate a schema from a cluster running a newer version of Cassandra but it contains invalid CQL:

```
2023-09-11 13:57:55,961 [info] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Creating schema using file '/tmp/schema.cql', keyspace: '<keyspace>'
2023-09-11 13:57:55,981 [warn] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Schema operation failed: Unknown property 'read_repair'
2023-09-11 13:57:55,983 [warn] c.a.l.s.r.c.CassandraCluster - Schema operation failed: Unknown property 'additional_write_policy'
```

I'm not aware of `read_repair` as a property and I don't think it exists in any version of Cassandra. There used to be table properties called `read_repair_chance` and `dclocal_read_repair_chance` which are associated with [read-repairs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html) (the process of synchronising/repairing replicas during a read request) but they have been deprecated since Cassandra 3.0.17, 3.11.3 and 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-13910](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13910)).

In any case, you will need to review your schema file (`/tmp/schema.cql`) and remove any references to `read_repair` since it is not a valid CQL schema syntax.

The table option `additional_write_policy` was renamed from `speculative_write_threshold` ([CASSANDRA-14820](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14820)) and is used for specifying a threshold for [Transient Replication](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/new/transientreplication.html), a new feature introduced in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-14404](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14404)) so it is not available in earlier releases of Cassandra.

[Amazon Keyspaces is based on Apache Cassandra 3.11.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/keyspaces-vs-cassandra.html) so it does not support Transient Replication:

> Amazon Keyspaces (for Apache Cassandra) appears as a nine-node, Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 cluster to clients and supports drivers and clients that are compatible with Apache Cassandra 3.11.2.

Since your CQL schema was sourced from a cluster running Cassandra 4.x+, you will not be able to import it into an Amazon Keyspaces instance. You will need to review the schema and rewrite it to not include new features. This means that if you were planning to import the SSTables from the Cassandra 4.x cluster, they will not be compatible with Amazon Keyspaces since they are on a different SSTable format. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for the explanation. After changing the /tmp/schema.sql to AWS keyspace 3.11.2 native table was created and service is now running. 

By going through the Cassandra JIRA project I was able to understand more when the properties were introduced.

Regards,
BKV